# Storyboard not restarting from initial position

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I am working on an animation using two storyboards. It plays properly at first, but on playing it the second time the first storyboard does not display at all. This is a sample of my code.

```
    <UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1920" Height="1080"
                         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:vMixTitleLibrary;assembly=vMixTitleLibrary">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image2">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-476"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image1">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="236"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Programme">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="236"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image1">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-1312"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Programme">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-1312"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image2">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-968"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
  <Grid>
    <Image Source="UpNextBar.png" Name="Image1" Width="1199" Height="100" Margin="48,871,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    <Image Source="UpNextText.png" Name="Image2" Width="368" Height="177" Margin="41,735,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    <my:TextBlockDesign Fill="#FF000000" FontSize="64" Text="Programme Title" Name="Programme" Width="984" Height="74" Margin="223,885,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <my:TextBlockDesign.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
            </my:TextBlockDesign.RenderTransform>
        </my:TextBlockDesign>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The animation plays the first time it is overlay-ed, but storyboard1 does not appear the second time. When the overlay is removed, it appears at the position storyboard1 was supposed to end and proceeds to play storyboard2 animation.

Please any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Please change to a more generic example, so i can reproduce your issue. Im kinda tapping in the dark with just the Trigger and StoryBoard

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a more generic example. That code is about all there is in the animation. At the press of play button, it makes "image1" come in from the left, while the textblock and image2 enters from below. pressing the button for storyboard two makes "image1" go out from the top, while textblock and image2 move out from the left. That happens as expected. But when i press the play button again to restart the animation, nothing happens. At the press of the second button however, it suddenly appears and moves out.

Comment: @Anselm Your XAML only shows UserControl and where are these image1 and image2 ?

Comment: @Anselm I have used the Storyboard and its working fine.

Comment: It works fine on first play, but on the second play it doesn't. I am using the animation in a vMix(a video mixing software). I will edit the initial code to show everything in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup first keyframe at storyline as your default title and set property HIDDEN, then put your animation as usuall.
So after playing storyline2 and playing again storuline1 all your object set to default position and would be hidden, and then play properly again